# How to create a map of sets from stream of pairs?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a problem with a specific Java stream to create a map containing sets.
I found *a* way, but I feel like that there is a better (more performant and or readable) way to express that.

Any ideas how to improve this would be highly appreciated!

#### Idea

input:

```
[["A", 1], ["A", 2], ["B", 3], ["D", 1], ["D", 5]]
```

output:

```
["A"={1, 2}, "B"={3}, "D"={1, 5}]
```

#### Implementation

```java
public static <L, R> Map<L, Set<R>> pairsToMap(Stream<Pair<L, R>> pairs) {
    return pairs.collect(
        Collectors.toMap(Pair::getLeft,
            // FIXME: Creating a new HashSet for each Pair... :/
            p -> new HashSet<>(Collections.singleton(p.getRight())),
            // merge existing set with new set
            (a, b) -> {
                a.addAll(b);
                return a;
            }
        )
    );
}
```

*Note:* **Pair** is my own implementation and is basically the following:

```java
public class Pair<L, R> {
    /* ... */
    
    public L getLeft() { /*...*/ }

    public R getRight() { /*...*/ }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more like a `groupingBy` than a `toMap`:

```
public static <L, R> Map<L, Set<R>> pairsToMap(Stream<Pair<L, R>> pairs) {
    return pairs.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Pair::getLeft, 
        Collectors.mapping(Pair::getRight, Collectors.toSet())
    ));
}
```

`groupingBy` allows you to specify a way to further collect each group. In this case, we want to first map to the right element, then `toSet`.

Comment: Ah thx mate, I already tried `Collectors.groupingBy()` but I didn't know about `Collectors.mapping()`